# How to wait for child process to set variable in parent process?

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, fork, ipc, child-process

```
 use Parallel::ForkManager;    
 my $number_running = 0;
 my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(30); 
 $pm->run_on_start( sub { ++$number_running; } );
 $pm->run_on_finish( sub { --$number_running; } );
 for (my $i=0; $i<=100; $i++)
 {
     if ($number_running == 5) { while ($number_running > 0) {} }  # waits forever
     $pm->start and next;
     print $i;
     $pm->finish;
 }
```

The above code uses [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm) to execute code in a for loop using parallel processes.  It is counting how many child processes are running and setting the `$number_running` variable accordingly.  Once 5 child processes are running, I would like it to wait until 0 child processes are running before continuing.

The first line in the for loop is designed to achieve this but it waits forever on that line.  It's like the change to the variable made by the child processes is not available to that line of code.  What am I doing wrong?  Note: I am aware of `wait_all_children` but I don't want to use it.

Comment: You shouldn't spin in an idle loop like that. Your parent process will use up all the CPU time it can get, endlessly testing the value of `$number_running`.

Comment: How can I wait until `$number_running` is decremented to zero by the child processes?

Comment: @CJ7  Child processes cannot affect `$number_running` used in the parent -- child and parent processes cannot write to each other's variables. The parent has to decrement this variable for itself.  Please see explanations added to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Short**   The callback `run_on_finish` normally doesn't get triggered for every child's exit, so `$number_running` doesn't get reduced and thus it can't control the loop.  Ways to fix this:

- use `reap_finished_children` in order to communicate as individual children exit, so that `run_on_finish` indeed gets to run as each child exits
- use `wait_for_available_procs` to wait for the whole batch to finish before starting a new set of processes

As for the title ("*How to wait for child process to set variable in parent process?*"), a *child process cannot set anything in the parent, nor could parent in the child*. They must communicate to accord actions, using some form of Inter-Process-Communication ([IPC](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc)). This module provides some of that, and a few methods useful for this question are outlined above.

---

The callback `run_on_start` runs with every new process and the counter is incremented. But the callback `run_on_finish` is never triggered so the counter is never decremented. Thus once it reaches `5` the code sits in the `while` loop. Note that a parent and children are separate processes which thus don't know about each other's variables and cannot change them.

The callback `run_on_finish` is commonly triggered by having `wait_all_children` after all processes were forked. Its job is also done
when maximum number of processes run and one exits.  This is done in `start` by a call to `wait_one_child` (which calls `on_finish`, see below).

Or, this can be done at will by calling [reap_finished_children](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager#reap_finished_children) method

> This is a non-blocking call to reap children and execute callbacks independent of calls to`start` or `wait_all_children`. Use this in scenarios where `start` is called infrequently but you would like the callbacks executed quickly.

This resolves the main concern of **how to communicate as individual children exit** (as clarified in comments), and not by `wait_all_children`.

Here is an example of how to use it so that the callback runs right as a child exits. A good deal of the code is merely for diagnostics (prints).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Parallel::ForkManager;    
$| = 1;

my $total_to_process = 3;  # only a few for this test
my $number_running   = 0;    
my @ds;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(30);

$pm->run_on_start( sub {
    ++$number_running;
    say "Started $_[0], total: $number_running";
});
$pm->run_on_finish( sub {
    --$number_running;
    my ($pid, $code, $iden, $sig, $dump, $rdata) = @_;
    push @ds, "gone-$pid";
    say "Cleared $pid, ", ($rdata->[0] // ''), ($code ? " exit $code" : '');
});

foreach my $i (1 .. $total_to_process)
{
    $pm->start and next;
    run_job($i);
    $pm->finish(10*$i, [ "kid #$i" ]);
}
say "Running: ", map { "$_ " } $pm->running_procs;  # pid's of children

# Reap right as each process exits, retrieve and print info
my $curr = $pm->running_procs;
while ($pm->running_procs) 
{
    $pm->reap_finished_children;    # may be fewer now
    if ($pm->running_procs < $curr) {
        $curr = $pm->running_procs;
        say "Remains: $number_running. Data: @ds";
    }
    sleep 1;  # or use Time::HiRes::sleep 0.1;
}

sub run_job {
    my ($num) = @_;
    my $sleep_time = ($num == 1) ? 1 : ($num == 2 ? 10 : 20);
    sleep $sleep_time;
    say "\tKid #$num slept for $sleep_time, exiting";
}
```

Use of this method is equivalent to calling `waitpid -1, POSIX::WNOHANG` in a loop after `fork`.  This forks fewer than the max (`30`) processes to see output more easily and demonstrate that the callback runs right as a child exits.  Change these numbers to see its full operation.

A child process exits with `10*$i`, so to be able to track children processes in the output. The data returned in an anonymous array `[...]` is a  string identifying the child process. As soon as the `reap_finished_children` call completes the `$number_running` is reduced, in the callback.  This is the reason for having the `$curr` variable, again for diagnostics.

This prints

```
start: Started 4656, running: 1
start: Started 4657, running: 2
start: Started 4658, running: 3
Running: 4656 4658 4657 
        Kid #1 slept for 1, exiting
Cleared 4656, kid #1 exit 10
Remains: 2. Data: gone-4656
        Kid #2 slept for 10, exiting
Cleared 4657, kid #2 exit 20
Remains: 1. Data: gone-4656 gone-4657
        Kid #3 slept for 20, exiting
Cleared 4658, kid #3 exit 30
Remains: 0. Data: gone-4656 gone-4657 gone-4658
```

---

The direct question is of **how to wait for the whole batch to finish before starting a new one**. This can be done directly by [wait_for_available_procs($n)](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager#wait_for_available_procs(-$n-))

> Wait until `$n` available process slots are available. If `$n` is not given, defaults to *1*.

If `$MAX` is used for `$n`, that many slots will become available only once the whole batch completed.  What to use for `$n` can also be decided at runtime.

---

***Some details of module's operation***

When a child exits the `SIGCHLD` signal is sent to the parent, which it must catch in order to know that the child is gone (and to avoid zombies, in the first place). This is done by using `wait` or `waitpid`, in code or in the `SIGCHLD` handler (but only at one place). See [fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html), [Signals in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals), [waitpid](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html) and [wait](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wait.html).

We see from [P::FM's source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DLUX/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm) that this is done in `wait_one_child`  (via `_waitpid` sub)

> ```
> sub wait_one_child { my ($s,$par)=@_;
> ```

```
  my $kid;
  while (1) {
    $kid = $s->_waitpid(-1,$par||=0);
    last if $kid == 0 || $kid == -1; # AS 5.6/Win32 returns negative PIDs
    redo if !exists $s->{processes}->{$kid};
    my $id = delete $s->{processes}->{$kid};
    $s->on_finish( $kid, $? >> 8 , $id, $? & 0x7f, $? & 0x80 ? 1 : 0);
    last;
  }
  $kid;
};
```

which is used in `wait_all_children`

> ```
> sub wait_all_children { my ($s)=@_;
> ```

```
  while (keys %{ $s->{processes} }) {
    $s->on_wait;
    $s->wait_one_child(defined $s->{on_wait_period} ? &WNOHANG : undef);
  };
}
```

The method `reap_finished_children` used above is a synonym for this method.

The method `wait_one_child` that gets the signal is used by `start` to reap child processes when maximum number of processes is filled and one exits. This is how the module knows when it can start another process and respect its maximum. (It is also used by a few other routines that wait for processes.
). And this is when `run_on_finish` gets triggered, by `$s->on_finish( $kid, ... )`

> ```
> sub on_finish {
> ```

```
  my ($s,$pid,@par)=@_;
  my $code=$s->{on_finish}->{$pid} || $s->{on_finish}->{0} or return 0;
  $code->($pid,@par);
};
```

The callback is in the coderef `$code`, retrieved from the object's `on_finish` key, which itself is set in the sub `run_on_finish`. This is how the callback is set up, once that sub runs.

The methods availed to the user for this are `wait_all_children` and `reap_finished_children`.

Since none of this is used in the posted code the `$number_running` is not getting updated so `while` is an infinite loop. Recall that the variable `$number_running` in the parent *cannot be directly changed* by child processes.

Comment: `run_on_finish` is executed every time a child process finishes. `$number_running`is updated by the child processes. I have tested this myself. I don't want to use `wait_for_children`.  I want to know how to wait for `$number_running` to be decremented to zero by the child processes.

Comment: @CJ7 1. The child has nothing to do with the counter.  Child code is what we type after `start`.  2. You _want to_ `wait` (or `waitpid`) for children, that is the first rule of forking. 3. The program is informed of child's exit via signals, which it must catch (and handle) in order to actually know that the child exited. The other way would be for a child to `pipe` back (or send a `SIGUSR` signal) to say that it is extiing, but we type child code so that is not the case. 4.  I finally got to look at the source code, this `wait`-ing is indeed done in `wait_all_children`. I'll update my post.

Comment: @CJ7  The `while` is clearly infinite, which can only be because `$number_running` doesn't get updated, even though the child processes do exit very shortly after they are created.  This can only be because the callback doesn't run.  When I comment out `wait_all_children` I see the confirmation of it -- the `Cleared PID` lines start being printed only after all processes have been forked.

Comment: OK, I can see in the source that `finish` is not calling `on_finish`, but I don't understand why that can't happen.  Why can't it do that?

Comment: @CJ7  I just tried it -- set the limit to 10 but ran only 5 processes (and removed `wait_all_children`).  It never printed `Cleared ...`, the callback never executed.  Please watch though, this can result in zombies. Some systems take care of that, but it cannot be expected in general.

Comment: @CJ7 If I may ask, why do you not like `wait_all_children`?  Its code is standard and clear, this is more or less what I do by hand in my signal handlers.

Comment: I just want to see that the callback can occur at the end of a child process because I may want to use for it for other reasons.  I don't see why a callback can't be called at the end of a child process.

Comment: Can `$pm->reap_finished_children` be used in this situation?  Would it achieve my aim?

Comment: @CJ7 I just got around to complete this -- the post is entirely rewritten.  There is a direct way to track each child, just as you expected, and it is by the method you mentioned.  There is also a direct way to wait for a batch to finish.  Let me know whether it needs edits.  (I will tweak and add anyway, it's just too much to get right at once, for me.)  I suggest that we clean up many of the comments, as they do not directly relate to the post now.  Let me know if you are OK with that.

Comment: @CJ7  I hope that this provides both things that you needed, as I understood them.  Please let me know if that isn't the case, or if more code/source commentary would be useful.