# How to stop forking in this code

Tags: perl, fork

So I have a perl script that goes out there and wgets pieces of a stream (I don't know how many pieces there are upfront)

but I can't think of a good way to know when to STOP wget'ing. right now if wget returns unsuccessful, than we create a file called "end" and once the main program sees it, it stops the loop. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Obviously it would be easy if it was done sequentially instead of concurrently, but i was trying to make it download the fastest.

```
my $link = $ARGV[0];
my ($url) = $link=~ m/(.+-)\d+.ts/i;

my $num = 0;

#while the file END doesn't exist
my @pids;
while (! -e "END") {
        #create the URL, increment by 1
        my $video=$url.++$num.".ts";
        die "could not fork" unless defined (my $pid = fork());

        #child process goes until wget returns invalid, create END
        if (not $pid) {
                system ("wget -T 5 -t 5 $video");
                `touch END` if $? != 0;
                exit;
        }
        push @pids, $pid;
}

#parent process still running, waiting for the same END file.
for my $pid (@pids) { waitpid $pid,0; }

print "pids finished\n";

sleep 1;
`rm END`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't indicate how many processes there may be, but no resource is unlimited and you should limit the number or you'll see a rapid degradation of performance as you reach saturation.

This is even more so when going out on the network since you may be annoying a server (and things will also stop being faster quite soon).  Perhaps run up to a few tens of processes at a time?

Then one option is to limit a number of parallel downloads using [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Parallel-ForkManager-1.19/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm). It has a way to [return data to parent](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/YANICK/Parallel-ForkManager-1.19/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm#RETRIEVING-DATASTRUCTURES-from-child-processes), so a child can report failure. Then its `run_on_finish` method can check each batch for such a flag (of failure), and set a variable that controls the forking.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Parallel::ForkManager;    

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(2);  # only 2 for a managable demo
my $stop_forking;

# The sub gets 6 parameters, but only first (pid) is always defined
# The last one is what a child process may have passed
$pm->run_on_finish(  
    sub { $stop_forking = 1 if defined $_[-1] } 
); 

for my $i (0..9)
{
    last if $stop_forking;

    $pm->start and next;    # forks
    my $ret = run_job($i);  # child process

    # Pass data to parent under a condition
    if ($ret eq 'FAIL') {  $pm->finish(0, \$ret) }  # child exits 
    else                {  $pm->finish }
}
$pm->wait_all_children;

sub run_job { 
    my ($i) = $_[0];
    sleep 2;
    print "Child: job $i exiting\n";
    return ($i == 3 ? 'FAIL' : 1);
}
```

This stops forking after the batch of jobs within which `$i == 3`. Add prints for diagnostics.

The "callback" `run_on_finish` runs only once a whole batch completes.<sup>†</sup> The *anonymous sub* in it always receives 6 arguments, but only the first one, the child pid, is always defined. The last one has data possibly passed by the child, and when that happens we set the flag. A child can return data by passing a reference to `finish` method. To only indicate a condition we can simply pass anything. I use `\$ret` as an example of passing actual data.

See documentation for more, but this does what you ask.  For yet *far* more see [Forks::Super](https://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super).

---

If you wish to fork as you do, I'd first put in a little `sleep` there, so you don't bombard the server with too many requests.  Your children can talk with the parent using [socketpair](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/socketpair.html). The failed child can write while all others can simply close their socket. The parent keeps checking, for example with `can_read` from [IO::Select](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html). There is an example in [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html). Since you only need children to write to the parent the [pipe](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pipe.html) would suffice as well.

You can also do it with a signal. The child that fails sends (say) `SIGUSR1` to the parent, which the parent traps and sets a global variable that controls further forks. This is simpler as the parent only traps that one signal and doesn't care where it comes from. See [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) and [sigtrap](http://perldoc.perl.org/sigtrap.html) pragma.

You can also use a file, much like you do, which is probably simplest since here you don't care about racing issues (whether children writes overlap), but only about an empty file showing up.

However, in all these you'd also want to limit the number of parallel processes.

Finally, there are also modules that help with external commands, for example [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.94/lib/IPC/Run.pm).

---

<sup>†</sup> To run the callback right as each child exits use [reap_finished_children](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager#reap_finished_children). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39071940/4653379).

Comment: thanks for the info i'll do some research.  I don't know how many files there are to a particular stream so right now i go until wget fails. but you're right i should take the server into consideration and not bombard it.  the last one i ran was over 357 pieces of the video. it did download really fast though.

Comment: @genx1mx6 I hope it helps, even as it mostly lists approaches. I plan on adding code with `P::FM` (it's late here now). The parent simply runs through the loop so those 357 got created right away and you probably hit the server with all that right off the bat. There must've been even more, since it takes the parent no time to be back in the next iteration forking yet another, so it just keeps spinning them.  Even as one fails there is probably a whole bunch already attempting to download other non-existing files. Btw, the file you use is fine -- but you need to limit the number.

Comment: @genx1mx6  I added a working example with `Parallel::ForkManager`. I can add code for other methods as well, but let me know how this goes.