# Parallel::ForkManager - what is better way to share hash between parent and child?

Tags: perl

I want to get a hash with all elements from all children using `Parallel::ForkManager`.

```
use strict;

use Parallel::ForkManager;

my @arr2 = (a, b, c, d);

foreach ( @arr2 ) {

    $pid = $pm->start

    $hash{$_} = localtime;

    # STORE ABOVE ELEMENT TO EXIST HASH

    my $pid = $pm->start and next;
}

$pm->wait_all_children;

READ %hash
```

#### output

```
$hash{a} = 11:02
$hash{b} = 11:03
$hash{c} = 11:04
$hash{d} = 11:05
```

Is it possible to share elements of hash by `run_on_exit` callback? Or I must use an external file? Which module does it in the easiest way? I tried IPC::Shareable and DBM::Deep. They do not work on my script.

Comment: It will work for Parallel::ForkManager ??

Comment: Parallel::ForkManager` provides for a child process to send data back to parent, explained in its docs. The downside is that it uses files for this. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41891334/4653379) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40434889/4653379) for examples.

Comment: I tried IPC::Shareable. Had erros `IPC::Shareable::SharedMem: shmget: File exists at /home/f/perl5/lib/perl5/IPC/Shareable.pm line 567.` In DBM::Deep I had errors `DBM::Deep: Cannot write to a deleted spot in DBM::Deep. at ./backtest.pl line 581` and others. I read about run_on_exit and this way don't looking easy in my case.

Comment: Show your code using DBM::Deep and IPC::Shareable

Answer (score 0):

Threads can share data easily:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q = 'Thread::Queue'->new;

my @workers = map 'threads'->create(sub {
    $q->enqueue([ 'threads'->tid, scalar localtime ]);
}), 1 .. 4;

$_->join for @workers;

my %hash;
while ($q->pending) {
    my $data = $q->dequeue;
    $hash{ $data->[0] } = $data->[1];
}

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash;
```

Comment: [*"The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged"*](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html)

Comment: @Borodin: I understand that people at IRC are tired of answering the same questions again and again, but I still don't understand why their feeling is reflected in the official documentation.

Comment: For details see https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2015/05/msg227743.html or http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1107534 .

Comment: That's very interesting; thank you.

Comment: I'm using ForkManager not threads. I wrote this in question.

Comment: @F.Grela: **choroba** is saying that it would be simpler to use threads instead.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question. I asked for a module to store the hash. I still have not found a solution.